# Cauchy Condensation Test Usage

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove the following series convergence using CCT:

$ c > 1$

$\sum \frac{1}{n\ln(n)^c}$ is convergent

Applying CCT I get:

$\sum \frac{2^n}{2^n*\ln(2^{nc})}$ == $\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\sum 1/nc$

Note that CCT can be used given the following conditions have been met:

(1) the sequence is $ > 0 \  \forall n \in N$

(2) the sequence is monotonically decreasing

I'm unclear as to how to proceed forward since $\sum 1/nc$ is divergent since $\sum 1/n$ is a diverging series

Comment: It seems that there is confusion about the symbol: $\ln (x) ^n$. Would you please clarify as to whether $\ln (x)^n=\ln (x^n)=n\ln x$ or  $\ln (x)^n=(\ln x)^n$?

Comment: Yes! it's (lnn)^c and thus n = $2^n$ it is (ln2^n)^c = n^cln2^c.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should have
$$\sum_n \frac{2^n}{2^n \ln(2^n)^c}=\frac 1{\ln^c 2}\sum_n \frac 1{n^c}$$
which converges when $c > 1$.

Comment: @Milten good catch, I got sloppy.

Comment: you're saying $\sum 1/ln(2^{nc})$ = 1/ln(2^c)*$\sum 1/(n^c)$.  By what property of ln does this follow from?

Comment: @mathcompguy your summand is $f(n) = (n\ln(n)^c)^{-1}$, so $f(2^n) = (2^n\ln(2^n)^c)^{-1}$, $\ln(2^n)=n\ln(2)$ is a standard log identity.

Comment: @gaucho-perez you're saying $ln(2^n)^c = n^c*ln2^c$ ignoring the outside $2^n$ and the inverse since those are not material to the equality statement that you're using for the proof?

Comment: @mathcompguy I am not ignoring the inverse, but yes, the first equality in your comment is what I am using.

Comment: so $ln(2^n)^c$ = $ncln2 = n*n^{c-1}*c*ln2 \implies 1=n^{c-1}$ which is not equal for $n > 1$.  Am I mistaking something here?

Comment: @mathcompguy yes, since $\ln(2^n)^c=(n \ln 2)^c$, not $nc\ln 2$.

Comment: yes correct with the parenthesis outside the ln: (ln2^n)^c

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

This is  a Bertrand's series, and the  (much simpler) classical proof uses *Cauchy's integral test*: the convergence of the series is equivalent to the convergence of the integral
$$\int_2^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x(\ln x)^c}.$$

Comment: @Milten: Yes; It seems I messed up on typing. Thank you for  pointing it!

Comment: At the first glance, it looked like *"This is Bernard's series"* $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Why mine? This belongs to a well-known family of series.

Comment: Yes, I know it. Just my sleepy mind seems to interchange your nickname with the series name. Never mind :)

Comment: thanks but we're not allowed to use integration for the proof.

Comment: Well, it's very unfortunate. But perhaps your teacher thinks ‘ Why complicate one's life to make things simple, when it's so simple to make them complicated?’.

Answer (score 0):

As $\frac{1}{n\ln(n)^c} = \frac{1}{c \cdot n\ln(n)}$, then, possibly, more direct is to use [Cauchy integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). As summand is positive and outgoing from derivative sign is decreasing, then series $\sum \frac{1}{n\ln^p(n)}$ is converged together with integral
$$\int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\ln^p x} = \frac{1}{(p-1)(\ln 2)^{p-1}}$$
when $p \gt 1$.

Comment: Your first equation assumes the meaning is $\ln(n)^c = \ln(n^c)$ (which I believe is not intended in the problem), but the rest of your answer assumes it means $\ln^c(x)$.

Comment: Also the integral evaluates to $\frac{1}{(p-1)\log^{p-1}(2)}$.

Comment: @Milten.  To you second comment, then you was right and I am grateful for pointing to typo and fixed it. As to first comment: in op is exactly $\ln(n)^c$, so first sentence is in full consent with second, where is considered more general case with $p$. Second answers first taking $p=1$. Consequently, answer is correct and I think it's only fair to wait my comment, when you did not understand something, then down vote based on wrong belief.

Comment: Fair enough. In general I believe it's fine to vote based on the current state/readability of an answer, and then one can just change the vote after an edit or clarifying comments. Please don't see it as an attack <3. As for this post, it definitely wasn't clear to me that you were generalizing the problem, but I can see what you mean now. In the meantime, OP has confirmed that $\ln(n)^c=\ln^c n$, so you answer doesn't really match the question. But I'll remove the downvote because your generalization coincides with the original question.